# Find key that exists on object based on an array of keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object called `obj` that will have one of several different keys: `message`, `msg`,  or `error`.

Using lodash's `_.intersection` and `_.keys`, I'm able to get keys inside `obj` that are also in the array `['message', 'msg', 'error']`.

```js
const message = _.intersection(_.keys(obj), ['message', 'msg', 'error']);
```

If `obj` is:

```js
const obj = {
  msg: 'hello'
};
```

Then `message` should be an array with a single string:

```js
message: ['msg'];
```

How can I use Lodash to instead get `message` to be the string value for the key?

```js
message: 'hello';
```

Comment: Append `[0]` at the very end.

Comment: @ChrisG That will change it to `msg`, not `hello`.

Comment: What should happen if the intersection returns more than one key?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, well, once you have the key, getting the value is kinda straightforward, isn't it? Didn't think I'd have to spell it out. As far as I'm concerned, this question is about getting from `[a]` to `a`. So the solution given `obj` and `message` is: `obj[message[0]]`

Comment: For this object, there would be only one of the three keys on there.

Comment: And a simple look up with `obj[message]` makes sense. it's been a long day =(

Comment: Btw, if `obj` is always going to have exactly one key, you can simply do `Object.values(obj)[0]`

Comment: It will only have one of those select keys, but it will have other keys besides those

Comment: @ChrisG What we think is obvious is not so much to newbies

Comment: This should also work: `const message = obj.msg || obj.message || obj.error;`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG -- I originally was using the multiple `||` one you have above, but decided against it thinking I could find something cleaner. (but maybe not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash's [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick) method to get an object with intersecting keys from your array will also work. You can then use [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#values) to get an array of values from this object, and [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the first value from this array:

```js
const obj = {
  msg: 'hello'
};

const [message = 'default'] = _(obj).pick(['message', 'msg', 'error']).values();
console.log(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do this with `_.pick` or `_.pickBy` before I posted this. Thanks.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, and I learned some things. Thanks again

Comment: @rpivovar no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the result of the intersection as the dynamic key of the object.

```js
const obj = {
  msg: 'hello'
};
const key = _.intersection(_.keys(obj), ['message', 'msg', 'error']);
const message = key.length == 1 ? [obj[key[0]]] : [];
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `Object.entries`? And you can evaluate using an expression to see if the key is equal to 'msg'.

```js
const obj = {
    msg: 'hello'
};

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (key === 'msg') {
        console.log(value);
    } else if (key === 'message') {
        // Do something for key 'message'
    } else if (key === 'error') {
       // Do something for key 'error'
    } else {
      // Else
    }
}
```

Or how about without underscore JS using reduce.

```js
const obj = {
    msg: 'hello',
};

const result = Object.values(obj).reduce((key, value) => {
    if (key === 'msg') {
        console.log(value);
    } else if (key === 'message') {
        // Do something for key 'message'
    } else if (key === 'error') {
       // Do something for key 'error'
    } else {
      // Else
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: He's looking specifically for one of the keys in `['message', 'msg', 'error']`

Comment: But what if the key is `message` or `error`? The whole point is that he doesn't know specifically which key it will be, he has an array of all the possible keys.

Comment: That's why he used `_.intersection()`

Comment: That's when you do nothing, but he knows what key they are. That's how we know it's either message, msg, or error. All intersection does is, computes the list of values that are the intersection of all the arrays. Each value in the result is present in each of the arrays. So seeing if it is present works.

Comment: But your code only works for `msg`, not the others.

Comment: @Barmar I have been responding to you, I was going to add them.

Answer (score 0):

If your object has one key and you have to have one value each time:

```js
const obj = {
  msg: 'hello',
};

const message = [obj[_.intersection(_.keys(obj), ['message', 'msg', 'error'])]];

console.log(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If you want to have multiple values, then:

```js
const obj = {
  msg: 'hello',
  message: ' this is great'
};
var message=[];
var keys = _.intersection(_.keys(obj), ['message', 'msg', 'error'])||[];

for(key of keys){
  message.push(obj[key]);
}
console.log(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```